# Overriding the mechanism of "Apply Promo Code"

Tags: php, shopping-cart, cs-cart

Is there any possibility in CSCART where I can override the mechanism of "Apply Promo Code" with my own ? I want to integrate a 3rd party loyalty system and I want to use the same Apply Promo Code process. I could not find any hook for this process. If there is none, Would I be able to hide the apply promo code box using any option of I must edit the .tpl file ?

CS-CART ver. 4.6.1

Comment: not a full answer, but this might help https://forum.cs-cart.com/topic/49238-how-to-disable-coupon-code-field-from-cart-and-checkout/

Answer (score 0):

In CS-Cart you can override tpl files completely (yes every single one). Although this is often frowned upon, it would be a fitting solution for your problem.

https://docs.cs-cart.com/4.8.x/developer_guide/core/coding_standards/hooks.html

Kind regards,

Answer (score 0):

Check default "Gift Certificates" addon. It works in the required way - extends default  "Apply Promo Code" mechanism.